# Why my individual working BDD test case not working, if they were running in tag mode?

Tags: bdd, python-behave

The test scenarios that I am dealing with is to login to a web page => get into profile tab => try different combinations to have a profile created, updated and deleted, etc. There is nothing special there.

And this is the first time I am using BDD framework to create "feature" files, their steps in python.

So far, I have created some test cases and was able to run individual ones in such command:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o .\allure_reports
 features\profile.create.case1.feature

behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o .\allure_reports
 features\profile.create.case2.feature
     ...
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty -o .\allure_reports
 features\profile.delete.case10.feature
```

But if I was to have a subset of my test features running in a tagged way, such as:

```
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -f pretty --tags @create -o
 .\allure_reports features
```

It always have the first feature executed, but the rests are failed. What could be wrong ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Lots of things could be wrong. But we can try to narrow down on some of the errors by taking a look at what the error output is. Please provide the error output.

Comment: Yeah. Need more information but possibly it is what is happening in between each test. Test1 executes and when Test2 starts Test1 has not cleaned up so Test2 starts in an unexpected state.

Comment: For questions like this, you will need to include the following information: A) What error are you getting (including stack trace); B) The Gherkin code for one of the scenarios; C) And quite possibly the step definitions used in the feature file.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, folks. After reviewing my code, I have realized what went wrong. While one case does not do the official log-out, the follow-up case is trying to start from the login page. -:)   It works ok if each one is running individually, but fails when they are executed in a chain.  Thanks for the help. -Jack

Comment: I haven't used `python-behave` but I suspect your command line argument should be: `--tags create` (without the `@` sign).